# React JS login Page - Why does If Condition fail to process values from json file?

Tags: json, reactjs, api

I'm attempting to develop a login page that operates off of the following .json file: https://api.myjson.com/bins/fyufr

I implemented an output to the console, which displays the results of the json file. The Issue I'm encountering, when I click the button on the form after the username and password are entered, the login page fails to direct the user to the landing page. The submit button login is written in the function **onSubmit**

This is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Login.css';

const divStyle = {
    margin: '40px',
  };

  const divStyleI = {
        width: '600px',
  };

class Login extends Component { 

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { 
            data: [], 
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/fyufr', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
            },
        }) /*end fetch */
        .then(results => results.json()) 
        .then(data => this.setState({ data: data })   
    )}

    onSubmit() {
       if (this.state.username.value == '{userName}' && this.state.password.value == '{password}' ){
        this.state.history.push("/memberinfo");
        }
    }

    //render component
    render() {
    console.log(this.state.data);
        return (
            <div style={divStyle}>            
                <h2>Member Login</h2>
                    <div style={divStyleI}>

                    <form>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label for="username">User Name:</label>
                            <input 
                                className="form-control"
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="Enter User Name"  
                                name="username"
                                  />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group"> 
                            <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                            <input 
                                className="form-control"
                                type="password"
                                placeholder="Enter your password"  
                                name="password"
                                  />
                        </div>
                        <div>

                             <input 
                             className="btn btn-primary"
                             type="submit" 
                             value="submit"
                             onClick={() => this.onSubmit()}
                              /> 
                        </div>
                   </form>

                    </div> 

            </div> 
        );
      }
}

export default withRouter(Login);
```

this is the json sample w/ test data:

```
[
    {
        "userName": "aknightt",
        "firstName": "Adam",
        "lastName": "Knight",
        "password": "password1",
        "token": "ayJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ8.ayJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1lIjoiR3JlZyIsInVuaXF1ZV9uYW1lIjoiZ2dyYWZmIiwibmJmIjoxNTI1MTIyOTQ5LCJleHAiOjE1MjUyMDkzNDl9.BzTaSSODX1yreo14dx_N-ucPnDgGbbJXusGLnZhWd9A"
    },
    {
        "userName": "ckeaton",
        "firstName": "Calvin",
        "lastName": "Keaton",
        "password": "password2",
        "token": "KyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ8.hyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1lIjoiR3JlZyIsInVuaXF1ZV9uYW1lIjoiZ2dyYWZmIiwibmJmIjoxNTI1MTIyOTQ5LCJleHAiOjE1MjUyMDkzNDl9.BzTaSSODX1yreo14dx_N-ucPnDgGbbJXusGLnZhWd9C"
    },
    {
        "userName": "esprite",
        "firstName": "Emma",
        "lastName": "Sprite",
        "password": "temp2",
        "token": "LyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ8.jyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1lIjoiR3JlZyIsInVuaXF1ZV9uYW1lIjoiZ2dyYWZmIiwibmJmIjoxNTI1MTIyOTQ5LCJleHAiOjE1MjUyMDkzNDl9.BzTaSSODX1yreo14dx_N-ucPnDgGbbJXusGLnZhWd9C"
    }
]
```

could I get some guidance as to what I'm doing wrong? ...Thanks in Advance

Comment: Replace `this.onSubmit` with `() => this.onSubmit()`. Your code should crash otherwise.

Comment: @Sulthan, I attempted your suggestion (please see edits in my code), but I still get the same results. Do you have any other suggestions? thank you

Comment: Do you see any errors? You are using function hansleSubmit which us not defined in your code.

Comment: @Sulthan, ok, it was my intent to remove the handlesubmit from the form tag. I applied the modification, but still the result is the same. I do not get any errors though. Any other suggestions?, ...thanks

Comment: Well, your `input` elements are not even connected to `state` and the `state` contains only `data` which is an empty array. How comes `this.state.username.value` does not crash?

Comment: @sulthan - in the render method, I have console.log(this.state.data); ...which is output\ing the results of the json file to the console. I can see the users. However, you make a valid point as far as the inputs not being hooked up to the state; I though I was setting username and password to the state via the if condition.  So what would be the correct approach in connecting my inputs to the state? thanks again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170235/discussion-between-user1724708-and-sulthan).